# how to detect android studio file modification events

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I need to visualize how a project develops over time.

I have used this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview
as basis for detecting when any project file has been modified locally.

The current setup is Android Studio on windows 7. And my problem is that the java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds from the example only gets fired when the programmer manually does a "ctrl-s". 
How do I detect Android Studios file modifications realtime?.

My fallback approach is to to set a timer an traverse all files. But i'd rather if I could just catch the appropriate file.

EDIT: solved with an IntelliJ plugin, took me 1/2 day.

first the tutorial from: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development#GettingStartedwithPluginDevelopment-anchor3

and using the menuaction to start/stop a BulkFileListener:

```
public class Watcher implements BulkFileListener {

private final MessageBusConnection connection;

public Watcher() {
    connection = ApplicationManager.getApplication().getMessageBus().connect();
}

public void initComponent() {
    connection.subscribe(VirtualFileManager.VFS_CHANGES, this);
 }

public void disposeComponent() {
   connection.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void before(List<? extends VFileEvent> events) {
   //logging done
}

@Override
public void after(List<? extends VFileEvent> events) {
    //logging done
}
}
```

placed the . jar in ...\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.1.3\plugins
and imported as instructed in the tutorial.

Comment: I believe that you can build a script to monitore the respective project's folder and as soon as some file has been changed, perform what do you want to.

Comment: That is what the java example does, but it seems that Android Studio holds everything in temporary files and only writes changes upon: close, ctrl-s and when you view the files from another program (such as explorer). I have tried traversing the file tree (with some set interval) and inspecting the file.lastModified() attribute, but it is not set unless the afore mentioned events happens.

Comment: Currently im using javas Robot to press "ctrl-s" with small delays this forces android studio to update files, anything smarter out there?